# How to show pointwise/uniform converge for Fourier series in general

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

I have asked this question before but I did not get any answers so I hope it is OK if I ask again.

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in $C_{\text{st}}$ which satisfies that
$$
f(x) = 6x+2
$$
when $-\pi < x < \pi$. Then I have to argue for or against if the Fourier series converges pointwise or uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. I have asked this question before but as $C_{\text{st}}$ is not common notation I hope I can get some more answers when defining what it means.

I would very much like to know how to tackle these kinds of questions as they most definitely will be a part of my analysis exam in three weeks.

> Definition: Let $C_{\text{st}}$ be the set of the functions $f:
>  \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which satisfies that
>
> 1. $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic
> 2. $f$ is piecewise continuous on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$
> 3. $f$ is normalized in its points of discontinunation meaning that $f(x) =\frac{f(x_{-})+f(x_{+})}{2}$

Futhermore we also need the following

> Definition: Let $C^1_{\text{st}}$ be the set of the functions $f:
>  \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which satisfies
>
> 1. $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic
> 2. $f$ is piecewise differentiable on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$
> 3. $f$ is normalized in its points of discontinunation

Then my book says that

> Definition: The Fourier series for a function $f \in C^1_{\text{st}}$
>   converges pointwise towards $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$

and

> Definition: If $f \in C^1_{\text{st}}$ and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ then the Fourier series for $f$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Then to prove pointwise convergence, are these definitions sufficient to show that $f$ is piecewise differentiable on $[-\pi,\pi]$ as $f \in C_{\text{st}}$?

Then to prove uniform convergence, are these definitions sufficient to show that $f$ is piecewise differentiable on $[-\pi,\pi]$ as $f \in C_{\text{st}}$ and that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You should always edit your previous question to explain notations/add context instead of asking a new question.

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a number of questions here, likely covered in your book, but it could be helpful to list non-exhaustively some of the main results regarding the convergence of Fourier series.  Apologies if long, but I hope it will be a helpful checklist for you.

We shall assume $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C $ is $2\pi$-periodic.  We consider the normed Lebesgue integrable spaces, $L^1(-\pi,\pi)$ and $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, recalling that on a bounded interval $L^2 \subset L^1$.  We can associate any $f$ in either $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ or $L^1(-\pi,\pi)$ with its Fourier series, writing
$$f \sim \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_k e^{ikx}  \quad\text{and}\quad
S_n(f,x) = \sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_ke^{ikx} $$
where each coefficient is given by $\displaystyle a_k =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-ikx} ~dx $.  The integrals exists for $ f \in L^2 $ or $L^1$.

The most common covergence results are :

1. **Convergence in $L^2$ norm.**  For all $f \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ 
   $$\left\lVert S_n - f \right\rVert_{L^2} \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty $$
   where the norm for any $f$ is $ \displaystyle \lVert f \rVert_{L^2} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \lvert f(x) \rvert^2 ~dx $.
2. **Parseval.** For all $f \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{k=-n}^{n} |a_k|^2 \to \lVert f \rVert^2$ as $n \to\infty$
3. **Pointwise convergence (Jordan).** Let $x_0 \in \mathbb R$. If $f \in L^1(-\pi,\pi)$ has bounded variation on an interval $[x_0-r, x_0+r]$ for some $ r > 0$. Then the limits $$f(x_0+) = \lim_{h \searrow 0} f(x+h) \quad\text{and}\quad f(x_0-) = \lim_{h\searrow 0} f(x-h) $$
   both exist and $S_n(f,x_0) \to \dfrac{1}{2} ( f(x_0+) + f(x_0-) ) $. 
   This resulte embodies the **localisation principle** where the convergence of $f$ at $x_0$ depends only on its characteristics in an arbitrarily small interval around $x_0$.
4. **Uniform convergence.**  If $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic, continuous on $\mathbb R$ (note that implies $f(\pi) = f(-\pi)$) and piecewise continuously differentiable (i.e. the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ can be divided into a finite number of sub-inetrvals $I_j, j=1, \cdots, m$ and $f$ is continuously differentiable in each $I_j$, with one sided derivatives at the end points) then the Fourier series $S_n(f,x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$.
5. **Gibbs phenomena.**  For a function $f$ that is piecewise continuous, convergence at points of discontinuity is non-uniform.  In fact the the maximum error between $S_n(f,x)$ and $f(x)$ has positive limit.

The function $f(x) = 6x+2$ meets the criteria for 1,2,3 but not 4 because there is no definition at $x = \pm \pi$ that would allow the function to be continuous there.  The Fourier series at $\pm \pi$ converges to the mid point $\frac{1}{2}(f(0+)+f(0-)) = 2$.

Comment: So the Fourier Series converges pointwise but not uniormly In this instance?

Comment: Furthermore, you say that in 4. uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$ implies that $f(\pi) = f(-\pi)$ which in this case is not correct. Is this what you mean when you say there "there is no definition at $x = \pm \pi$ that would allow the function to be continuous there"?. I guess so. Or is it because that $f(x)$ is defined in the open interval from $(-\pi,\pi)$. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Hi. On uniform convergence,:  $ f(\pi) = f(-\pi)$  is sufficient when combined with the other properties.  I was not saying it is necessary, although in practice it will be.  And I added that in your example $f(x) =3x+2$, Which is defined only on the open interval, no values of $f(\pi)$ and $f(-\pi)$ can make it continuous.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. If you don't mind I have one last question.  This is a question from an Analysis exam which I am studying for. Another example is the given by the function $f \in C_{st}$ satisfying $f(x) = 1 + \cos(x/2)$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$. Here my professor has provided the answers and says that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, thus on $]-\pi,\pi[$ as well, with $f(-\pi) = f(\pi) = 0$ and $C^{1}$ on $\mathbb{R}$   he concludes that the Fourier series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. Doesn't this contradict what you are saying? Or am I misunderstand something? Thanks.

Comment: No. In this case the function meets the conditions of No 4.  It is periodic and continuous on the real line, which means it has equality at $\pm \pi$ and in this case it is also differentiable everywhere, which is stronger than needed by 4. So it converges uniformly on $[-\pi,\pi]$.  Then, as it’s periodic the uniform convergence equally holds true on the whole real line. Is that clearer?

Comment: I am not sure. Maybe it is because I don't understand continuity well enough but isn't $f(x) = 6x+2$ a well-known composition of a continuous function on the real axis. Thus $f$ is indeed continuous on the real axis which means $f$ is also continuous on $]-\pi,\pi[$? The only difference is the limits $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi^-} 6x+2 = 6\pi + 1 \neq \lim_{x \rightarrow -\pi^+} 6x+2 = -6\pi + 1$. Does this imply discontinuity in $\pm \pi$? And if so why?

Comment: I think I see.  The function is not equal to $6x+2$ on the whole real axis but just on $[-\pi,\pi]$.  The values on the rest of the real line are then determined from the requirement that is periodic.  That is why equality at the end of the range is important so the function joins each $2\pi$ Interval continuously to the next.  Fourier series only match periodic functions.

Comment: Thanks I see that. So to conclude: If I have to argue for or against that the Fourier series for $f$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ I have to prove continuity on $\mathbb{R}$ which includes $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi^-} = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\pi^+}$? which for $f(x) = 6x+2$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$ is not the case. Thus the Fourier series for $f$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Exactly.  And the other function you mentioned does. And remember for uniform convergence in addition to continuity, you need another condition.  To be piecewise continuously differentiable is a sufficient condition.

Comment: One last question: To then prove pointwise convergent I have to show that $f$ is differentiable and that $f'$ is continuous on the interval $-\pi<x<\pi$? My definition only says piecewise differentiable but doesn't $C^1$ imply that $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is continous?

Comment: And one last question if you don't mind: How do I use what you have said to prove/disprove convergence in $L^2?$? The definition in my books says that a sequence $\{f_n\} \in C_{st}$is said to converge towards $f \in C_{st}$ in $L^2$ if $||f-f_n|| \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Item 1 gives $L^2$ convergence. Pretty much every function meets the conditions.  Item 2 deals with point wise.  Any function reasonably well behaved will converge point wise at all points where $f$ is continuous and the mid point otherwise.